# how to simplify this equation

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

I know that:

$$\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}=\cos(\theta)$$

but I wonder is there way to simplify and rewrite equation above without the imaginary part? :

> $$\frac{e^{a+i\theta}+e^{-a-i\theta}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$. This gives us that
$$\dfrac{e^{a+i\theta} + e^{-a-i\theta}}2 = \dfrac{e^a(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)) + e^{-a}(\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta))}2 = \dfrac{\cos(\theta)(e^a+e^{-a}) + i \sin(\theta)(e^a-e^{-a})}2$$

Comment: Thank you very much, is there a way to simplify the equation without the imaginary part? like in the first equation we can write it as cos(\theta)?

Comment: @Dreamer: only if $\theta=k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ or $a=0$ would the answer be real, and then it would be $(-1)^k\cosh(a)$ or $\cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ e^{a+i\theta} + e^{-a-i\theta} = e^{i(\theta-ia)} + e^{-i(\theta-ia)} = 2\cos{(\theta-ia)}. $$
Or you can use hyperbolic functions to write it as $\cosh{(a+i\theta)}$. These are really the same thing.